# How to display the age of an nginx cached file in headers

Tags: linux, caching, nginx

I've set up a caching server for a site through nginx 1.6.3 on CentOS 7, and it's configured to add http headers to served files to show if said files came from the caching server (HIT, MISS, or BYPASS) like so:

```
add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
```

However, i'd like to see if there's a way to add a header to display the age of the cached file, as my solution has `proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;` set, and i'd like to check that it's respecting that setting.

So what i'm looking for would be something like:

```
add_header Cache-Age $upstream_cache_age;
```

I'm unable to find anything of the sort though, can you help?

Thanks

Comment: You can either hard code those response to add the time this record was cached and expiry in seconds and let your program do the calculation, or you need to use Nginx + Lua + Custom Cache module? Which approach is feasible for you?

Answer (score 8):

The nginx documentation is quite exhaustive — there's no variable with the direct *relative* age of the cached file.

The best way would be to use the [`$upstream_http_`](http://nginx.org/r/$upstream_http_) variable class to get the *absolute* age of the resource by picking up its `Date` header through `$upsteam_http_date`.

```
add_header X-Cache-Date $upstream_http_date;
```

For the semantic meaning of the `Date` header field in HTTP/1.1, refer to [rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2](//tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.2), which describes it as the time of the HTTP response generation, so, basically, this should accomplish exactly what you want (especially if the backend runs with the same timecounter).

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time attempting to solve this with the [Nginx Perl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html), which does not seem to have access to [$upstream_http_NAME](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_http_) headers that would allow you to successfully calculate the current time from a timestamp header that your proxied application created during render time.

Alternatively, you could use a different caching layer architecture like Varnish Cache, which does indeed provide the `Age` HTTP response header:

http://book.varnish-software.com/3.0/HTTP.html#age

Comment: I had the same problem with the $upstream_http, and I solved it for LUA, you can probably do the same in Perl, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59437878/4932239

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution that works for this, with the Lua module, in this question: [Nginx: Add “Age” header, with Lua. Is this a good solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59437878/4932239)

I'm going to post here the code, for any suggestion it would be better to discuss it in the other link, where I explain it in more detail.

```
map $upstream_http_Date $mapdate {
    default $upstream_http_Date; 
    '' 'Sat, 21 Dec 2019 00:00:00 GMT';
}
```

Inside location:

```
header_filter_by_lua_block { 
   ngx.header["Age"] = ngx.time() - ngx.parse_http_time(ngx.var.mapdate); 
}
```